# Marklogic cts:element-value-query Or condition match

Tags: marklogic

doc1.xml

```
<note>COGNITIVE SCIENCE, EXPERIMENTAL DESIGN</note>
```

doc2.xml

```
<note> EXPERIMENTAL DESIGN, AI PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE, JAVA Online</note>
```

How can I construct a query to return documents that have condition COGNITIVE SCIENCE "OR" Java Online.  I use cts:element-value-query() but don't know how to add "OR" condition.

```
cts:uris(
    (),
    ("descending"),
    cts:and-query((
            cts:collection-query(("/courses")),
            cts:element-value-query(
                                    xs:QName("note"),"COGNITIVE   SCIENCE","case-insensitive")


    ))
)
```

Thanks in advance
Thichxai

Comment: cts:uris() will give you the URIs of those documents. If you actually want the documents themselves, take a look at cts:search().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cts:uris(
    (),
    ("descending"),
    cts:and-query((
      cts:collection-query(("/courses")),
      cts:or-query((
        cts:word-query("COGNITIVE SCIENCE","case-insensitive"),
        cts:word-query("Java Online","case-insensitive")
      ))
    ))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give a list of phrases to cts:element-value-query:

```
cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("note"),("COGNITIVE SCIENCE","Java Online"), "case-insensitive")
```